# SQL check for bit flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, bit

So the application has checkbox's that are bit flagged. Depending on what checkbox option is selected, the application will store it as an integer in the database. How can I query the int in the database to check if a specific bit is on/off.

Example:

```
Decimal   Binary
16        00010000
208       11010000
```

I want to check if the 5th bit is on or off (or any for that matter).

Comment: is that a varchar type?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't have a bit shift operator, but something like this works:

```
where decimal & power(2,5-1) > 0
```

Of course, using bit maps begs of the question:  Why aren't you just using a set of bit flags?  You can define each one individually, and the code is much easier to read.

Comment: It won't work :(  Not getting any proper results.

Yes, I would have used a set of bit flags but the application was built that way many years ago.

Comment: Shouldn't this return > 0 ?

Select '5th bit on'
Where 16 & (2^(5-1)) > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can define a bit shift operator in SQL by multiplying or dividing by 2

Examples of stored procedures to do this can be found here:
http://dataeducation.com/bitmask-handling-part-4-left-shift-and-right-shift/

Answer (score 0):

The way that seems to work for me is...

```
DECLARE @Unknown AS int = 0;
DECLARE @Orange AS int = 1;
DECLARE @Big AS int = 2;
DECLARE @Green AS int = 4;
DECLARE @Small AS int = 8;

DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    description INT
);
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE (id, name, description) VALUES (1, 'item one', @Big + @Orange);
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE (id, name, description) VALUES (2, 'item two', @Small + @Orange);
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE (id, name, description) VALUES (3, 'item three', @Small + @Green);
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE (id, name, description) VALUES (4, 'item four', @Unknown + @Green);


SELECT TOP 1
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MYTABLE WHERE (SELECT CASE description & @Small WHEN @Small THEN 1 WHEN 0 THEN 0 END) = 1) AS 'Small Items',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MYTABLE WHERE (SELECT CASE description & @Big WHEN @Big THEN 1 WHEN 0 THEN 0 END) = 1) AS 'Big Items'

DELETE @MYTABLE
```